# JavaScript update field in another UserControl

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I try to explain better. I have one user control in page, and inside this have UC2 (modal pop up). And I try to achieve this: When I close UC2(modal) i try to update some fields on UC1. And this works fine for one(I have UC2(modal) and on button Save OnClientClick="SaveInfoCI()"), and in UC1 on top of page

function SaveInfoCI() {
     document.getElementById("<%=frmData.FindControl("txtImplementingCI").ClientID%>").value
 = document.getElementById("<%=UC2.GetClientID%>").value;   }

but because i reuse this control in another place i want to update another field. Basically now i Have 3 JS function that update 3 fields. And I try when I click save in UC2(modal) I must execute one of this 3 javascript f, to update right field. I don't want to have 3 same UC with only difference in OnClientClick="SaveInfoCI().

Comment: have you considering using a javascript library like jquery? That could make your javascript look better. Then I would suggest to separate your javascript from your codebehind code, you can instead have your javascript to look up the id in a hidden field or specify with class names.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems: first, your syntax is off, when inside code behind you can't use the `<%=` like this.

Second problem, by the time this script is executed (on top of the page) the elements still does not exist. You have to change the value in the client side page load event.

So this should work, though it's better done server side:

```
sb.Append("window.onload = function() { document.getElementById('" + frmData.FindControl("txtTextBox").ClientID + "').value = document.getElementById('" + MyUserControl.GetJs + "').value; };</")
```

Also, you really don't need StringBuilder here.. use ordinary string instead.

Comment: Tnx for answer.Please can you check on top

Comment: @ziks edit your original post with your new details and delete your answer. Personally I have no idea what's going on, will try delve into it again when I have some more time.